# How to verify text using selenium on popup notification before vanishing it

Tags: selenium, testing, notifications, automation, popup

There is a requirement like **verifying Text using selenium on Popup notification** before vanishing.

Not find any suitable solution for this.Please help me in this use-case

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Additional info: use-case:: After creating organization, one pop-up notification should show with success message as: Organization created successfully with color code

Comment: At least show your pop-up HTML and a screenshot, There are several types of pop-up, we need to know your pop-up belongs to which type from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get text from popup after that you can assert with the expected text
String value =driver.switchTo().alert().getText();

Answer (score 0):

it is really unpredictable to understand your scenario.We must need pop-up HTML and a screenshot, and what problem you are facing.Sometime the pop up might be bootstrap modal or alert, so without knowing the popup, it is not possible to give the solution.Besides you can try simply find the element and use getText() function.If it is simple modal(Bootstrap), it will give you the text.

If you are struggling to find the element you can pause the JavaScript by using F8.

Comment: You can verify below image link for further information:


[Reference image](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Animated-Notification-Plugin-For-jQuery-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Growl.jpg)

In this example, you can find 3 different pop-up notifications, I need to verify those messages before vanish

Comment: You can directly get the text from jQuery UI Dialog Modal Popup that disappears after some delay. Simply find the locator for the area where the message is present and do normally like you do find the text of in any case. Hope this will work!